# SELECT WHERE sql query

Tags: android

I'm trying to match username and password in existing database and I'm stuck at that point in writing SQL query.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select " + dbh.name + dbh.pass
+ " from tablename where" +dbh.name +"="+ e1.getText().toString()+";", null);
```

Comment: This would lead to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using something as follows but is HIGHLY discouraged:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE "+COLUMN_USERNAME + " = '"+usrname+"' AND "+COLUMN_PASSWD+" = '"+passwd+"' "; 
//COLUMN_USERNAME is the column name which stores username COLUMN_PASSWD is column storing password
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

You can try to use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) class for the purpose. There are questions which deal with How to store username and passwords. You should checkout following threads:

1) [Android: Storing username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925486/android-storing-username-and-password?rq=1)

2) [Is it safe to store username + passwords in a local SQLite db in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205666/is-it-safe-to-store-username-passwords-in-a-local-sqlite-db-in-android)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code to this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select " + dbh.name + dbh.pass
+ " from tablename where " +dbh.name +"='"+ e1.getText().toString()+"'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

dbh.name + dbh.pass means what? is this both are different columns? if yes then you have to pass this both column name with comma like,

```
dbh.name +","+ dbh.pass
```

and fire select query like,

```
SELECT "+ dbh.name+","+dbh.pass +" FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE dbh.name=?", new String [] { e1.getText().toString() });
```

Hope this will solve your problem :)